# JSON to PHP Array using file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents, json

I am trying to fetch the below json content using a magazine api.
The output of the json is like this. i want the below json to convert to php array.

```
{
"bpath": "http://www.sampledomain.com/",
"clist": [
    {
        "cid": "11",
        "display_type": "grid",
        "ctitle": "abc",
        "acount": "71",
        "alist": [
            {
                "aid": "6865",
                "adate": "2 Hours ago",
                "atitle": "test",
                "adesc": "test desc",
                "aimg": "",
                "aurl": "?nid=6865",
                "weburl": "news.php?nid=6865",
                "cmtcount": "0"
            },

            {
                "aid": "6857",
                "adate": "20 Hours ago",
                "atitle": "test1",
      "adesc": "test desc1",
      "aimg": "",
                "aurl": "?nid=6857",
                "weburl": "news.php?nid=6857",
                "cmtcount": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cid": "1",
        "display_type": "grid",
        "ctitle": "test1",
  "acount": "2354",
        "alist": [
            {
                "aid": "6851",
                "adate": "1 Days ago",
                "atitle": "test123",
      "adesc": "test123 desc",
      "aimg": "",
                "aurl": "?nid=6851",
                "weburl": "news.php?nid=6851",
                "cmtcount": "7"
            },
            {
                "aid": "6847",
                "adate": "2 Days ago",
                "atitle": "test12345",
      "adesc": "test12345 desc",
      "aimg": "",
                "aurl": "?nid=6847",
                "weburl": "news.php?nid=6847",
                "cmtcount": "7"
            }
        ]
    },

]
}
```

My code looks like this.

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.testmagazine.com/test.php?type=menu";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The above code returns an empty array. :(
How is it possible to convert the above JSON to php object array.
I am helpless.

Thanks 
Haan

Comment: You're probably getting an empty array because the JSON object is malformed.  Try validating it via [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: What is the output of the print_r($data)?

Comment: @Jack & Aldo - Got my issue fixed . Shivam S.Kara code, finally worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The JSON sample you provided is not valid. Check it online with this JSON Validator http://jsonlint.com/. You need to remove the extra comma on line 59.

One you have valid json you can use this code to convert it to an array.

json_decode($json, true);

```
Array
(
    [bpath] => http://www.sampledomain.com/
    [clist] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cid] => 11
                    [display_type] => grid
                    [ctitle] => abc
                    [acount] => 71
                    [alist] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [aid] => 6865
                                    [adate] => 2 Hours ago
                                    [atitle] => test
                                    [adesc] => test desc
                                    [aimg] => 
                                    [aurl] => ?nid=6865
                                    [weburl] => news.php?nid=6865
                                    [cmtcount] => 0
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [aid] => 6857
                                    [adate] => 20 Hours ago
                                    [atitle] => test1
                                    [adesc] => test desc1
                                    [aimg] => 
                                    [aurl] => ?nid=6857
                                    [weburl] => news.php?nid=6857
                                    [cmtcount] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cid] => 1
                    [display_type] => grid
                    [ctitle] => test1
                    [acount] => 2354
                    [alist] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [aid] => 6851
                                    [adate] => 1 Days ago
                                    [atitle] => test123
                                    [adesc] => test123 desc
                                    [aimg] => 
                                    [aurl] => ?nid=6851
                                    [weburl] => news.php?nid=6851
                                    [cmtcount] => 7
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [aid] => 6847
                                    [adate] => 2 Days ago
                                    [atitle] => test12345
                                    [adesc] => test12345 desc
                                    [aimg] => 
                                    [aurl] => ?nid=6847
                                    [weburl] => news.php?nid=6847
                                    [cmtcount] => 7
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 14):

You JSON is not a valid string as P. Galbraith has told you above.

and here is the solution for it.

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.testmagazine.com/test.php?type=menu";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Use this code it will work for you.

Comment: I know that you are getting data from API so its not possible  for you to validate it. But my given code will work for you

Comment: Can you please choose my answer as a correct answer so that other people can use it.

Answer (score 2):

**Check some typo ','**

```
<?php
 //file_get_content(url);
$jsonD = '{
    "bpath":"http://www.sampledomain.com/",
    "clist":[{
            "cid":"11",
            "display_type":"grid",
            "ctitle":"abc",
            "acount":"71",
            "alist":[{
                    "aid":"6865",
                    "adate":"2 Hours ago",
                    "atitle":"test",
                    "adesc":"test desc",
                    "aimg":"",
                    "aurl":"?nid=6865",
                    "weburl":"news.php?nid=6865",
                    "cmtcount":"0"
                },
                {
                    "aid":"6857",
                    "adate":"20 Hours ago",
                    "atitle":"test1",
                    "adesc":"test desc1",
                    "aimg":"",
                    "aurl":"?nid=6857",
                    "weburl":"news.php?nid=6857",
                    "cmtcount":"0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cid":"1",
            "display_type":"grid",
            "ctitle":"test1",
            "acount":"2354",
            "alist":[{
                    "aid":"6851",
                    "adate":"1 Days ago",
                    "atitle":"test123",
                    "adesc":"test123 desc",
                    "aimg":"",
                    "aurl":"?nid=6851",
                    "weburl":"news.php?nid=6851",
                    "cmtcount":"7"
                },
                {
                    "aid":"6847",
                    "adate":"2 Days ago",
                    "atitle":"test12345",
                    "adesc":"test12345 desc",
                    "aimg":"",
                    "aurl":"?nid=6847",
                    "weburl":"news.php?nid=6847",
                    "cmtcount":"7"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
';

$parseJ = json_decode($jsonD,true);

print_r($parseJ);
?>
```