# Is there an easy way to read file contents in array format in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file

I am trying to make use of files(.txt) to print logs. Inside the file, it logs an array value which looks like this:

```
  Array
  (
      [NAME] => John Peters
      [AGE] => 24
      [COUNTRY] => United States
      [EMAIL] => test@test.com
  )
```

So now, I am trying to read the file contents and covert it onto an actual array so that I would be able to reference the value using the array key in a php file, something like:

```
  echo 'Name : ' .$person['NAME'];
  echo 'Age: ' .$person['AGE'];
  echo 'Country: ' .$person['COUNTRY'];
  echo 'Email: ' .$person['EMAIL'];
```

Is there a predefined php function to do it? Or how will I be able to accomplish what I want. I have tried to use the fread() and fgets() function but it doesn't really accomplish what I want or I might  be missing something.

Comment: Why do you log it like that in the first place? Just log JSON, then parse the file as JSON. Easy peasy.

Comment: Have you tried with [**file_get_contents( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ? See also this Q&A on SO => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529112/json-to-php-array-using-file-get-contents

Comment: You could also use `serialize()` on the data before storing it to your logfile, then when loading you use `unserialize()`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick script for you,
I assumed that in your (files).txt can contain many entries of `print_r` results e.g.

```
Array
  (
      [NAME] => John Peters
      [AGE] => 24
      [COUNTRY] => United States
      [EMAIL] => test@test.com
  )
Array
  (
      [NAME] => John Peters
      [AGE] => 24
      [COUNTRY] => United States
      [EMAIL] => test@test.com
  )
```

This script assumes that your inputs `test.txt` only contains array that has 1 level (so, it won't work with nested array)

```
$c = file_get_contents('test.txt');

# Matches all strings that has 'Array(...)' pattern
preg_match_all('#Array[^\)]+\)#', $c, $matches);

$items = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {

    # Extracts KEY => VAL patterns from matched text 
    if (preg_match_all('#\[([^\]]+)\].*?>(.*)#', $match, $array)) {
        $items[] = array_combine($array[1], $array[2]);
    }
}

# test your results
print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read it using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Eg:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('abc.txt');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: The problem is not reading in the actual contents of the file, it is to convert the data to it's appropriate value, convert it to an array in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Rezigned and I had the same idea... Here's what I came up with:

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents('log.txt');
  $file = preg_match_all('/(\s+\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]\s+=>\s+.+)\n/', $file, $lines);
  $key = array();
  $val = array();
  foreach ($lines[0] as $line) {
    $keys_vals = preg_split('/(\s+=>\s+)/', $line);
    $key[] .= preg_replace('/[\[|\]]/', '', $keys_vals[0]);
    $val[] .= $keys_vals[1];
  }
  $line_count = count($lines[0]);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $line_count; $i++) {
    print $key[$i] . ': ' . $val[$i];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function shared by Matt in PHP manual called `print_r_reverse`, I think it's what you want. The following code is copied from PHP manual `print_r` function comments section directly.

```
<?php 
function print_r_reverse($in) { 
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($in)); 
    if (trim($lines[0]) != 'Array') { 
        // bottomed out to something that isn't an array 
        return $in; 
    } else { 
        // this is an array, lets parse it 
        if (preg_match("/(\s{5,})\(/", $lines[1], $match)) { 
            // this is a tested array/recursive call to this function 
            // take a set of spaces off the beginning 
            $spaces = $match[1]; 
            $spaces_length = strlen($spaces); 
            $lines_total = count($lines); 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_total; $i++) { 
                if (substr($lines[$i], 0, $spaces_length) == $spaces) { 
                    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], $spaces_length); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        array_shift($lines); // Array 
        array_shift($lines); // ( 
        array_pop($lines); // ) 
        $in = implode("\n", $lines); 
        // make sure we only match stuff with 4 preceding spaces (stuff for this array and not a nested one) 
        preg_match_all("/^\s{4}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER); 
        $pos = array(); 
        $previous_key = ''; 
        $in_length = strlen($in); 
        // store the following in $pos: 
        // array with key = key of the parsed array's item 
        // value = array(start position in $in, $end position in $in) 
        foreach ($matches as $match) { 
            $key = $match[1][0]; 
            $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]); 
            $pos[$key] = array($start, $in_length); 
            if ($previous_key != '') $pos[$previous_key][1] = $match[0][1] - 1; 
            $previous_key = $key; 
        } 
        $ret = array(); 
        foreach ($pos as $key => $where) { 
            // recursively see if the parsed out value is an array too 
            $ret[$key] = print_r_reverse(substr($in, $where[0], $where[1] - $where[0])); 
        } 
        return $ret; 
    } 
}
```