# Can't get content with file_get_contents function

Tags: php, file-get-contents, imdb

I want to get movie Rating from IMDB website.
For example, I have a url http://p.media-imdb.com/static-content/documents/v1/title/tt1520211/ratings%3Fjsonp=imdb.rating.run:imdb.api.title.ratings/data.json
Run it and you can see the movie rating is 8.7 and I wan to get it, so I used this query:

```
$s="http://p.media-imdb.com/static-content/documents/v1/title/tt1520211/ratings%3Fjsonp=imdb.rating.run:imdb.api.title.ratings/data.json";
$s = file_get_contents($s);
$s=explode('rating":',$s);
$s=explode(',"rating',$s[1]);
echo $s[0];
```

But it doesnt work and I don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am checking the script out but uhm ye your array contains nothing check it with: print_r($s)
the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

updated

When you show the content it shows:

```
‹5KOÃ0„ÿJµ'šÄvÞ9U‚.‰³›LÁ¢y`o*UUþ;v ·õÎìÌg3ôÇØj6ãgl—ñáF‡¬©¹Ñ4#ÓH µ†ÏxÛlŽödñ³ÀñKï¥4Óe*€èˆ2¤DÕŠH×U‘zÔ"‡?q°Ó¡5^5i\gÕ’Ü´Ø¡ðÀ×Ùd“žMÌ¡õŸ.ÔšÐ—lÛ„YæJ()/l«€ù…Ý‡>{ÿîº¿Kí_0_Þa BÔÚR£„{êôè¿æ lx¤­š*.ï§iÙC—…Rb]1“$æ6
```

so your explode will also be checked to that string.

Code:

```
$s="http://p.media-imdb.com/static-content/documents/v1/title/tt1520211/ratings%3Fjsonp=imdb.rating.run:imdb.api.title.ratings/data.json";
$s = file_get_contents($s);
/*$s=explode('"rating":',$b);
$s=explode('"rating":',$b[1]);
print_r($s);*/

print($s);
```

updated:
also check the code with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

it seems like it has an error

I think you can find more in this question for your answer:
[json to php array using file get contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529112/json-to-php-array-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 links you can check regarding to this answer. I haven't checked it if it worked but on JSONLint I received an error in your JSON file

Comment: It seems there was an error in the JSON file. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: No problem, We are here to help people ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the PHP.ini setting `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, which means that remote URIs (ie http(s), etc) can not be opened using the file family functions (fopen,..)

Please also refer to [its config value description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) according to which it is a system wide setting, so I think you can not override it using [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Alternatively you could use the [cURL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), for details on how to use it please refer to its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Please run php info to check if the allow_url_fopen is set to ON

```
php_info();
```

But use the CURL for getting the content, which simulating an actual web client. 
Do not turn on this option, because it's not a good for security purposes