# How get data from url to array?

Tags: php, arrays, get

I use php pretty badly. I'm not a programmer just doing something for my private things. 
I have such a problem I would like to download data from my PV production. The data is in the form as below. How to download data from a url in php, respectively, to group them and send them to the array ??
Thank you in advance for all your help.

> {"sid":62923,"dataunit":"kWh","data":[{"time":"2019-08-01","no":"1","value":"27.7"},{"time":"2019-08-02","no":"2","value":"24.0"},{"time":"2019-08-03","no":"3","value":"19.9"},{"time":"2019-08-04","no":"4","value":"25.3"},{"time":"2019-08-05","no":"5","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-06","no":"6","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-07","no":"7","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-08","no":"8","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-09","no":"9","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-10","no":"10","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-11","no":"11","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-12","no":"12","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-13","no":"13","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-14","no":"14","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-15","no":"15","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-16","no":"16","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-17","no":"17","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-18","no":"18","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-19","no":"19","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-20","no":"20","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-21","no":"21","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-22","no":"22","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-23","no":"23","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-24","no":"24","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-25","no":"25","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-26","no":"26","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-27","no":"27","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-28","no":"28","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-29","no":"29","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-30","no":"30","value":"0.0"},{"time":"2019-08-31","no":"31","value":"0.0"}]}

Comment: read about function json_decode

Comment: seems like you got a data in json format so you need to use json_decode ();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON to PHP Array using file\_get\_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529112/json-to-php-array-using-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 

$json_url = file_get_contents('Your url goes here');
$data = json_decode($json_url,true);

var_dump($data);
// You can print all of your data here to see if it works
foreach ($data as $items) {
    // You can loop trough the data and get it like $items->sid etc
    var_dump($items);
}

?>
```

You need to grab the URL with '**file_get_contents**' and than you need to decode it with **json_decode**

and then you print it out with the for each function

Comment: Thx works but $data = json_decode($json,true);   -->    $data = json_decode($json_url,true);   ;)